# How to set new value for a key in Django Session_data

Tags: django, django-admin, django-sessions

What I have in my encoded session_data is:

```
'workspaceKey':'8d7f4b3106c740c1a54970a8b67d156d', 
'_auth_user_hash': '7e024dd67ccb0e2aaab9ac1a92887109f7f020e4', 
'_auth_user_id': '1', 
'_auth_user_backend': 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
```

What I have tried is (1st approach):

```
request.session['workspaceKey'] = "123f4b3106c740c1a54970a8b67d111d"
```

but it is not updating workspaceKey is my existing session_data

Another approach what I tried is:

```
sessionid = Session.objects.get(session_key=session_key)
sessionid.get_decoded()['workspaceKey'] = "8d7f4b3106c740c1a54970a8b67d111d"
```

Again it is not updating workspaceKey is my existing session_data.
I have also tried below combinations with respect to above approach

```
request.session.modified = True 
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST=False
```

My code is like this

```
session_key = request.data['sessionKey'] 
request.session['workspaceKey']= "somenewkey" 
request.session.modified = True 
sessionid = Session.objects.get(session_key=session_key) 
session_data= sessionid.get_decoded()
print session_data
```

What I expect in my output as (new workspace key should be updated)

```
'workspaceKey':'123f4b3106c740c1a54970a8b67d111d', 
'_auth_user_hash': '7e024dd67ccb0e2aaab9ac1a92887109f7f020e4', 
'_auth_user_id': '1', 
'_auth_user_backend': 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
```

Comment: How do you know it's not updating? The first method is the correct and only way of doing it; sessions are to be treated as dictionaries.

Comment: I am printing updated session_data and it reflects the old value. still I will give another try.

Comment: Where are you printing it? Show the whole view.

Comment: @Daniel 

`session_key = request.data['sessionKey']
request.session['workspaceKey']= "somenewkey"
request.session.modified = True
sessionid = Session.objects.get(session_key=session_key)
session_data= sessionid.get_decoded()
print session_data `
--
** output **
 session_data

{u'workspaceKey': u'8d7f4b3106c740c1a54970a8b67d156d', u'_auth_user_hash': u'7e024dd67ccb0
e20d0b9ac1a92887109f7f020e4', u'_auth_user_id': u'1', u'_auth_user_backend': u'django.cont
rib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'}

Comment: Please put that code as an update to the question and format it appropriately. But the Session object won't be modified until the view returns and the SessionMiddleware runs its `process_response` method. As I mentioned, there shouldn't be a need to access the Session table directly.

Comment: thanks @DanielRoseman Is there any way to run `process_response` after manual update

Comment: No and I can't think why you'd want to. If you need to access the session data within the view, use `request.session`. There is no need to do anything else.

Comment: Why some one put down vote here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below code works perfectly in order to change session_data of django session table.
**Re-encoding** the updated key of session_data provides updated session_data.So the key point is after decoding data encoding is must.

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
from django.contrib.sessions.backends.db import SessionStore
workspaceKey ="123f4b3106c740c1a54970a8b67d111d"
session_key = request.data['sessionKey']
sessionid = Session.objects.get(session_key=session_key)
session_data= sessionid.get_decoded()
print session_data['workspaceKey']
session_data['workspaceKey']= workspaceKey
encoded_data = SessionStore().encode(session_data)
sessionid.session_data = encoded_data
sessionid.save()
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to save and after you should fetch that session from db and decode that encrypted session will give you need updated session value.

Try below code that will give new session data

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
session_key = request.data['sessionKey'] 
request.session['workspaceKey']= "somenewkey" 
request.session.save()
session_obj = Session.objects.get(session_key=request.session.session_key).get_decoded()
print session_obj
```

Comment: Why is that so? Why can't I do `request.session.get_decoded('key')`?